# Look up value by "submission number" return "name"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have one sheet, with values such as this:

**Sheet A**

[image: Sheet A]

and another sheet with values like so:

**Sheet B**

[image: Sheet B]

What I would like to do is search in the **Sheet A** by "Submission Number", i.e. the values in column `A`, I want to search there using the values in column `B` of **Sheet B** and return the *Name* of the company, the value in **Sheet A**, column `B`.

I was trying something like this but it didn't work:

```
=LOOKUP(B2, eligible.submissions!B2:B160,1,1)
```

So in the example above, for row `1` in **Sheet B** I want to use the value `724`, i.e. (**Sheet B**, column `B`, row 1), to look in the Column `A` of **Sheet A**, there I would find that `724` corresponds to "*Advice Business Development*", and accordingly I want my function to return me that value, the name.

Is this possible with Google Sheets?

Which function to use?

I was also trying something like this:

```
=LOOKUP(B2, SheetA!B2:B160,SheetA!B2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Vlookup should do what you want.

```
VLOOKUP(B1;SheetA!A:B;2;FALSE)
```

This would be in A1 of SheetB

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
=LOOKUP(B2, eligible.submissions!A1:A158,eligible.submissions!B1:B158)
```